# git log until / since with date-time formatting

Tags: git, datetime-format, git-log

I am given some dates and times in `yymmdd-HHMMss` format, e.g: `231030-150735`, `231102-125814`, `231109-114532`, etc. I am interested in using these dates and times, as given, to limit the output of `git log master` between those dates and times. By default, the versions of `git` on both my local machine and my build server use `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss` format, so the equivalents of the above examples would be `2023-10-30 15:07:35`, `2023-11-02 12:58:14` and `2023-11-09 11:45:32`.

Limiting the commits between two dates in this default format works well and returns me data:

```bash
git log master --oneline --since='2023-11-02 12:58:14' --until='2023-11-09 11:45:32' | wc -l
101
```

Unfortunately, trying to apply my date-time format and applying the `--date=format:` flag to `git` does not appear to work:

```bash
git log master --oneline --date=format:%y%m%d-%H%M%S --since='231102-125814' --until='231109-114532' | wc -l
0
```

This is not too surprising given that the official [git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) mentions, under section "Commit Limiting":

> Note that these are applied before commit ordering and formatting
> options, such as --reverse.

By "these", it refers to commit limiting options, such as `--until` and `--since`, and `date=format:` is one of the "ordering and formatting options" that are mentioned.

Is there any way to enable this format for a specific `git log` query, without affecting global `git` configurations? Of course I can generate a `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss` format from a `yymmdd-HHMMss` format, but my only option to go from `yy` to `YYYY` is to prepend `"20"`, and my code will break after 2099. I don't want my grandkids to have to figure this out, if `git` and coding as we know it exists by then.

Comment: `--date=format:...` is only applied on the output. You will have to format your `since` and `from` to a format accepted by `--until` and `--since`. Note that `231102-...` already has the ambiguity your grandkids will have to deal with -- for example: in 2124, they would have to deal with that unit test you wrote next to your script :).